# how do I update an external bar chart by clicking on a node in a force directed network

Tags: javascript, layout, event-handling, protovis

I'm trying to update the contents of a bar chart by clicking on a node in a force directed network. Currently, I'm trying to use the "mousemove" event on the main panel with a "point" event that updates the variable activeNode which then informs which row I hope to access. I'm having trouble with the fact that my point event from the main panel doesn't update activeNode and its always set to its default value. Tried looking everywhere for a fix with this, but I think I'm missing some more fundamental concept.

Here is the code...

```
var w = document.body.clientWidth,
    h = document.body.clientHeight,
    colors = pv.Colors.category19(),
    activeNode = 0;

var vis = new pv.Panel()
    .width(w)
    .height(h)
    .fillStyle("white")
    .event("mousemove", pv.Behavior.point(Infinity));   

var force = vis.add(pv.Layout.Force)
    .width(w-200)
    .nodes(miserables.nodes)
    .links(miserables.links);

force.link.add(pv.Line);

force.node.add(pv.Dot)
    .def("o",-1)
    .size(function(d) (d.linkDegree + 10) * Math.pow(this.scale, -1.5))
    .fillStyle(function(d) d.fix ? "brown" : colors(d.group))
    .strokeStyle(function() this.fillStyle().darker())
    .lineWidth(1)
    .title(function(d) this.index)
    .event("mousedown", pv.Behavior.drag())
    .event("drag", force)
    .event("point", function() {activeNode = this.index; return vis;});

vis.add(pv.Label).top(20).left(w/2).text("activeNode = " + activeNode);

vis.add(pv.Bar)
    .data(topw[activeNode].splice(0))
    .top(function(d) this.index * 30)
    .left(w-80)
    .width(15)
    .height(20)
    .anchor("left").add(pv.Label)
        .textAlign("right")     
        .text(function(d) d[0]); 

vis.render();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here, but the basic one is conceptual - when you're declaring the properties on marks in your visualization, you can either use a value, like:

```
.width(10)
```

or a function, like:

```
.width(function() { return 10; })
```

The difference is that the second version will be re-evaluated each time you `render()` the vis (or the relevant part of the vis). So for example, where you have:

```
vis.add(pv.Label).top(20).left(w/2).text("activeNode = " + activeNode);
```

this will only be evaluated the very first time the vis is rendered. Instead, you need a function:

```
// assign the label to a variable, so we can refer to it later
// this is easiest if we define the label and bar first
var nodeLabel = vis.add(pv.Label)
    .top(20)
    .left(w/2)
    .textAlign("right") // easier for my bar layout
    // note that this has to be a function, so that it will be 
    // re-evaluated on re-render
    .text(function() {
        return "activeNode = " + (activeNode ? activeNode.nodeName : 'None')
    });
```

So your corrected code might look like this (I changed the bar chart a bit, since I don't have access to the `topw` data you reference):

```
var w = document.body.clientWidth,
    h = document.body.clientHeight,
    colors = pv.Colors.category19(),
    activeNode = null;

var vis = new pv.Panel()
    .width(w)
    .height(h)
    .fillStyle("white")
    .event("mousemove", pv.Behavior.point(Infinity));   

// assign the label to a variable, so we can refer to it later
// this is easiest if we define the label and bar first
var nodeLabel = vis.add(pv.Label)
    .top(20)
    .left(w/2)
    .textAlign("right") // easier for my bar layout
    // note that this has to be a function, so that it will be 
    // re-evaluated on re-render
    .text(function() {
        return "activeNode = " + (activeNode ? activeNode.nodeName : 'None')
    });

// again, assign the bar to a variable
// I think I'm missing some data for your example, so
// I made a single bar to show node degree
// (only one data point, so no .data() needed)
var nodeBar = vis.add(pv.Bar)
    .top(0)
    .left(w/2)
    .height(20)
    .width(function() {
        // make a scale based on all nodes
        var scale = pv.Scale.linear(
            // get the max link degree to be the upper limit of the scale
            0, pv.max(miserables.nodes, function(d) { return d.linkDegree; })
        ).range(0, 200);
        // return a value based on the active node
        return activeNode ? scale(activeNode.linkDegree) : 0;
    });

var force = vis.add(pv.Layout.Force)
    .width(w-200)
    .nodes(miserables.nodes)
    .links(miserables.links);

force.link.add(pv.Line);

force.node.add(pv.Dot)
    .def("o",-1)
    .size(function(d) (d.linkDegree + 10) * Math.pow(this.scale, -1.5))
    .fillStyle(function(d) d.fix ? "brown" : colors(d.group))
    .strokeStyle(function() this.fillStyle().darker())
    .lineWidth(1)
    .title(function(d) this.index)
    .event("mousedown", pv.Behavior.drag())
    .event("drag", force)
    .event("point", function(d) {
        // set the global variable to point to the current node
        activeNode = d;
        // re-render the label
        nodeLabel.render();
        // re-render the bar
        nodeBar.render();
    });

vis.render();
```

Comment: thanks - you are more or less the protovis master on s.o. I see you on lots of these questions.

Comment: @shigeta - I see your shameless effort to get me to answer your other Protovis question :). Apparently it worked - score one for flattery.